# Usar parámetros al pasar una función por referencia en PHP

Tags: php, revisión-de-código, xampp, paso-por-referencia, php5

Tengo un script que funciona con la siguiente función por referencia:

```
elseif ($opcion == "fref") {
            function &calcref($base,$altura,$anchura){
               $productoref=$base*$altura*$anchura;
                return $productoref;
            }
            $productoref = &calcref($base,$altura,$anchura);
            echo "El producto usando referencia es $productoref";
```

Ahora me piden lo siguiente:

> Utilizando una función definida por el usuario que reciba los 3 parámetros desde el formulario y devuelva el volumen mediante un cuarto parámetro de salida pasado por referencia.

Pero no termino de entender el concepto, ni cóomo pasar el 4º parámetro.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Gracias, pero ya me he molestado en mirarlo ahí, y no termino de entender cómo operar con el parámetro **Volumen**

Comment: ahora mismo pasas tres parámetros. Añadir uno más es trivial. En cuanto a pasar por referencia, ¿qué intentaste?

Comment: Es un ejercicio teorico? si no es asi, ultimamente no tiene mucho sentido utilizar los pasos por referencia, ya que puedes devolver uno o varios resultados en el mismo return, simplemente añadiendolos en un **vector asociativo** (por ej). Ademas,(al menos en php) es recomendable pasar como mucho 2 parametros. Si hay que pasar más, el tercero deberia ser un array asociativo que contenga el resto de parametros que necesitas en tu función. Por supuesto, si es un ejercicio teórico no le quiero quitar valor, pues es interesante entender el paso por referencia.

Comment: No es teórico, muy a mi pesar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pasar por referencia quiere decir, más o menos, que el argumento que le estás pasando a la función es la variable misma y no solo su valor.

```
<?php
function calcref($base,$altura,$anchura, &$resultado){
    $resultado=$base*$altura*$anchura;
}

$resultado = null;
calcref(5,5,5, $resultado);

echo $resultado;
```

En este caso, pasamos como cuarto argumento, por referencia, la variable en la que almacenaremos el resultado de nuestra operación, lo cual hará que fuera de la función, `$resultado` mantenga el valor que se le asignó dentro de la función.

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos el siguiente ejemplo

```
<?php

function &func()
{
    //estatic para mantener el valor de $i
    static $i = 0;
    // Incrementamos $i
    $i++;
    // Retornamos
    return $i;
}

/**
 * Se ejecuta la funcion y
 * se referencia: return $i;
 */
$valor = &func(); // $i = 1

echo "valor:", $valor; // 1
echo "valor:", $valor; // 1
func(); // $i = 2
func(); // $i = 3
echo "valor:", $valor; // 3
?>
```

Por lo que tu ejemplo podria quedar así

```
<?php
// definimos la funcion
function &VolumenCubo($base,$altura,$anchura)
{
    // establecemos una cuarta variable para el volumen
    static $volumen = 0;
    // Calculamos y asignamos el resultado
    $volumen=$base*$altura*$anchura;
    // Retornamos $volumen
    return $volumen;
}
// Referenciamos la funcion
$productoref = &VolumenCubo(5,5,5);
echo $productoref; // 125

VolumenCubo(6,6,6);
echo $productoref; // 216
?>
```

Comment: Según OP, el resultado no debe asignarse como retorno de la función, sino como un cuarto parámetro pasado por referencia.

Comment: Cierto, no entendí correctamente el enunciado y me olvide que el cuato parametro debe ser una referencia.